# Riak unrecoverable disk failure

Tags: riak, riak-cs, riak-ts

I have a 3 node Riak cluster with each having approx. 1 TB  disk usage. All of a sudden, one node's hard disk failed unrecoverably.
So, I added a new node using the following steps:

1) riak-admin cluster join
2) down the failed node
3) riak-admin force-replace failed-node new-node
4) riak-admin cluster plan
5) riak-admin cluster commit.

This almost fixed the problem except that after lots of data transfers and handoffs, now not all three nodes have 1 TB disk usage. Only two of them 
have 1 TB disk usage. The other one is almost empty. This means there are no longer 3 copies on disk anymore. What commands should I run to forcefully make sure there are three replicas on disk overall without waiting for read-repair or anti-entropy to make three copies ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer got by posting same question to riak-users@lists.basho.com :

(0) Three nodes are insufficient, you should have 5 nodes
(1) You could iterate and read every object in the cluster - this would also trigger read repair for every object
(2) - copied from Engel Sanchez response to a similar question  April 10th 2014 )
* If AAE is disabled, you don't have to stop the node to delete the data in
the anti_entropy directories
* If AAE is enabled, deleting the AAE data in a rolling manner may trigger
an avalanche of read repairs between nodes with the bad trees and nodes
with good trees as the data seems to diverge.

If your nodes are already up, with AAE enabled and with old incorrect trees
in the mix, there is a better way.  You can dynamically disable AAE with
some console commands. At that point, without stopping the nodes, you can
delete all AAE data across the cluster.  At a convenient time, re-enable
AAE.  I say convenient because all trees will start to rebuild, and that
can be problematic in an overloaded cluster.  Doing this over the weekend
might be a good idea unless your cluster can take the extra load.

To dynamically disable AAE from the Riak console, you can run this command:

> riak_core_util:rpc_every_member_ann(riak_kv_entropy_manager, disable, [],
>   60000).

and enable with the similar:

> riak_core_util:rpc_every_member_ann(riak_kv_entropy_manager, enable, [],
>   60000).

That last number is just a timeout for the RPC operation.  I hope this
saves you some extra load on your clusters.
(3) That’s going to be :
(3a) List all keys using the client of your choice
(3b) Fetch each object

https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/reading-objects/

https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/secondary-indexes/